# possible to constrain jQuery resize to x or y axis, like drag constrain?

Tags: jquery, resize, axis, constraints

This jQuery lets you constrain drag movement so it occurs only on the axis specified:

```
$("#draggable2").draggable({ axis: 'x' });
```

See: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#constrain-movement

This is not legal jQuery but I wish it were:

```
$("#Container").resizable({ minHeight: 150, containment: {axis:'y' } });
```

Is it possible to prevent the user from making #Container wider while allowing her to make it taller?

Thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, it's possible by using UI events. Along the x-axis:

```
$("#Container").resizable({
    resize: function(event, ui) {
        ui.size.width = ui.originalSize.width;
    }
});
```

or along the y-axis:

```
$("#Container").resizable({
    resize: function(event, ui) {
        ui.size.height = ui.originalSize.height;
    }
});
```

Comment: This may not work anymore. I tried hard coding the ui.size.width in the resize event and found that it was ignored. Maybe some change to jquery broke this solution.

Comment: turns out this will work in jquery ui 1.9 but not 1.10; i've submitted it as a bug

Answer (score 29):

Both of these answers work, but they have the unfortunate consequence of showing a <-> cursor over the eastern border, making the user think they might be able to resize the width. What I think is a better match is to call this on the jQuery object:

```
.resizable({handles:'s'})
```

since this will simply remove the possibility of changing the width, and the cursor.

Comment: Love this answer. UI friendly, which is kinda the point. If you ever decided to use a ghost or a helper, the other methods would mislead and possibly frustrate your users. This is simple, elegant, and not processor intensive.  Also note that you can use `{handles: 's, n'}` or `{handles: 'n'}` if you so choose, you are not restricted to only being able to resize on the bottom edge

Comment: This also works with bootstrap, the accepted answer causes the resized area to become a little smaller every time you resize.

Answer (score 4):

I found that just clearing on the height or width inline style on the object on resize also works. It also has the added benefit of not being bound to the object's original dimensions (since those could change based on the contents)

```
$("#Container").resizable({
    resize: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).css('height','');
    }
});
```

Comment: This is a great solution. I have a really tall resizable, so I only show the handle on the `se` corner, otherwise it'd be missed. Setting the max and min height didn't seem to work given the content reflows as the resizing happens.

Comment: The only working solution here, considering you are using the latest version of jQuery UI. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I see two ways for you to do this, one better than the other. The best one first:

1) Set minWidth and maxWidth to the same value (namely the value you want the width to remain).

```
$('#theThing').resizable({ minWidth = 200, maxWidth = 200 });
```

2) Create a parent element with fixed width and make that the containment. I don't know how this will work on the height, but by default a `div` with no height specified grows if its content does, so it might work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Tomas. Unfortunately, when #theThing is contained inside #Container and #Container has no explicit height:   $("#theThing").resizable({ minHeight: 150, containment: '#Container' }) then theThing cannot be resized vertically. #Container simply does not grow beyond the height it needs to render #theThing in the first place.

Comment: @Tim, did you try the other way - setting min and max width to the same value? This is what I'd do, rather than having a container.